# How to hide row in VBA with criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

Relatively new to VBA.

My data looks like this:

```
Join Date   Date
1 Oct       1 Oct
1 Oct       1 Oct
3 Oct       1 Oct
.
.
.
```

I want to code it such that
If Join Date > Date, hide the whole row. This should loop through the whole of Join Date column.

Can’t seem to find a solution for it.

Current code:

```
Sub Hiderows()

For Each a in Range((“G6”),Range(“G6”).End(xlDown))
     If a.Value > a.Offset(0,1).Value Then
        a.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End If
Next a

End Sub
```

Cell G6 is where the first Join Date starts from

Comment: Sorry, edited with my current code!

Comment: `For Each a In Range("G6", Range("G6").End(xlDown))`. Fix parentheses and change smart quotes to straight quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try below sub. Assuming Join Date is `Column A` and Date is `Column B`.

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each rng In Range("A2:A" & lRow)
        If rng.Value > rng.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
            rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen Oh, Sorry! Updated. Thanks for pointing it.